# QTCP Server is not sending message to client

Tags: python, sockets, pyqt4, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

Hi I have created a tcp server with Qtcpsocket in pyqt4. I am easily receiving the messages from clients. but this server fails to send messages to client. Please let me know where i am doing wrong.

```
    def sendMessage(self):

    print('send message is called')
    message = 'OKVTdddddssssddssss'

    reply = QtCore.QByteArray()
    reply.append(message)
    stream = QtCore.QDataStream(reply, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    stream.setVersion(QtCore.QDataStream.Qt_4_0)
    stream.writeUInt16(0)
    stream.writeQString(message)
    stream.device().seek(0)
    stream.writeUInt16(reply.size() - SIZEOF_UINT16)
    self.tcp.write(reply)
```

Comment: what is `self.tcp` and do you actually use `stream`?

Comment: Class Socke(QtNetwork.QTcpSocket):
         def __init__(self):

        QtNetwork.QTcpSocket.__init__(self)

Comment: self.tcp is Qtnetwork.qtcpsocket().

Comment: so self.tcp.read work well for me and i receive messages fromclients but as long as server has to send some message="msg", it just dont do good. i dont receive any message on clients

Comment: @Zavi. Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok @ekhumoro thanks for your guidance